# Why doesn't this JavaScript to replace text with links not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a Chrome extension which upon page load will replace text identified by a regex with whatever text I want in its place. Now instead of replacing it with more text I'd like to replace text with a hyperlink, but I'm running into trouble. This code just breaks pages:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var element = elements[i];

  for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
    var node = element.childNodes[j];

    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        var text = node.nodeValue;
        var replacedText = document.createTextNode( text.replace(/dog/gi, 'jQuery') );
        var aLink = document.createElement('a');
        aLink.href = "http://google.com";
        aLink.appendChild(replacedText);
        element.replaceChild(aLink, node);
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the console outputting for an error.

Comment: Just a guess, but is it running forever, because the loop (based on a live list) descends recursively into the previously just-created `<a>`? You need to specify what you mean by "breaks".

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink the approach because when a text node contains matches it needs to be sliced down in multiple text nodes and links. For example this (one text node):

```
dog woof dog woof
```

becomes this (one link, one text node, one link, one text node):

```
<a>...</a> woof <a>...</a> woof
```

Here's how I would do it:

```js
    //get all text nodes in an array
    var root = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var n, text_nodes=[], walk=document.createTreeWalker(root,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
    while(n=walk.nextNode()) text_nodes.push(n);

    var regex = /dog/i;

    for(var ii = 0; ii < text_nodes.length; ++ii) {
        var text_node = text_nodes[ii];
        
        //treat each match one at a time
        var index;
        while(-1 !== (index = text_node.nodeValue.search(regex))) {
            //create link
            var link = document.createElement("a");            
            link.setAttribute("href", "http://stackoverflow.com");
            link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("cat"));

            //new text node is everything preceding the match
            text_node_before = document.createTextNode(text_node.nodeValue.substr(0, index));
            
            //old text node becomes the rest
            text_node.nodeValue = text_node.nodeValue.substr(index).replace(regex, "");

            text_node.parentNode.insertBefore(text_node_before, text_node);
            text_node.parentNode.insertBefore(link, text_node);
        }
    }
```

```html
<p>dog dog cat <strong>boing boing</strong> dog woof</p>
```